How to replace/fill div values in the Table.Cell React
I have a React table and I want to load all general data on the loading. And data that is not already loaded, I want it to be stored like empty lines.
For example, I have a Table.Cell in the Table.Row and it stores like:

name 2. age 3. capital

age and capital does not load straightaway, so I make additional API call and till I get the response from the server, I want it to be stored like

Some name

just empty row without nothing

the same empty row


Then after getting the response, I want to fill this table cell with gotten data.
I want empty columns because I don't want to have table shifting after api response...
That's what I've tried
const init = value => {
    return [
        <div key={0}>{value}</div>,
        <br></br>,
        <br></br>
    ];
};

Initially, it fills properly, but then when I try to fill age and capital
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        return value.map((item, index) => <div key={index}>{item}</div>);
    }

    return value;
};

it just creates additional 4th and 5th row in the cell and stores like :
Some name
just empty line in the table
empty line
17 age
1 million euro capital
I tried to use styles like display: inline or block, but it did not help.

i think you are looking in the wrong place for the problem
